# Web API (.Net Core 2) and Database (Created via Code first Entity framework) to Google Cloud

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to deploy a .Net Web Api along with Database (Microsoft SQL) created using Entity framework in Google Cloud is there any option

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-dotnet-applications

Comment: Dan, thanks for for the reply. I found a similar article, could you please check whether both are pointing the same. https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/hello-world

Comment: The information is related. To answer your question, yes there are options for deploying .NET applications to GCP. You should select an approach and try it.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/